# Изменить первую букву в слове

Tags: php

Мне нужна функция, чтобы изменить первую букву в слове на `э`, в случае если оно начинается с `е`.

Пример:

```
привет, я елбек
```

нужно заменить на

```
привет, я элбек
```

Comment: Конкретизируйте пример. Он непонятен.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev если слово начинается с `е`  то заменить на `э`

Comment: так что ли https://regex101.com/r/qMudZz/1 ?

Comment: teran спасибо за ответ, но на другой текста не работает код.

Comment: например: ўша пайтда «ишқорли газ» деб аташар еди.

Comment: или провертеть пожалуйста этот код...

Comment: function TranslitURL ($text, $translit = 'ru_en') { 
 $RU['ru'] = array( 
"Ё","Ю","Я","........
  ); 

 $EN['en'] = array( 
"Yo","Yu","Ya","Q","O`","....
  );
 if($translit == 'en_ru') { 
  $t = str_replace($EN['en'], $RU['ru'], $text);
  $t = preg_replace('/(?<=\s|^)е([а-я]+)(?=\s|$)/m', 'э$1', $t);
  } 
 else {
  $t = str_replace($RU['ru'], $EN['en'], $text);
  $t = preg_replace('/(?<=\s|^)е([а-я]+)(?=\s|$)/m', 'э$1', $t);
  }
 return $t;
}

Comment: Если ориентироваться на пример - то тупо заменить `' е'` на `' э'`... А вообще - сперва чётко определить, что есть "слово".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

function firstLetter($txt){
    return preg_replace('/\bе/iu','э',$txt);
}

echo firstLetter(' елбеке пошел войной на елбека');
```